# Why is the validation loss constant?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, image-segmentation

I am trying to use the unet model from Aladdin Persson on a custom dataset i made. The problem is 'during the training the training loss is decreasing while the validation loss is constant. And i just can't figure out what the problem is. I have 368 pictures in the training set and 51 in the validation set.
[Orange is validation loss and blue training][1]
I am also posting my training code and the part where i check the accuracy on the validation set.

This part is the train_fn.

```
for batch_idx, (data, targets) in enumerate(loop):
    #img = data.cpu().squeeze(0).permute(1,2,0).numpy()
    #plt.imshow(img)
    data = data.to(device=DEVICE)
    targets = targets.float().unsqueeze(1).to(device=DEVICE)
    
    # forward
    with torch.cuda.amp.autocast():
        predictions = model(data)
        loss = loss_fn(predictions, targets)
    # backward
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    scaler.scale(loss).backward()
    scaler.step(optimizer)
    scaler.update()
    
    running_loss += loss.item()

    # update tqdm loop
    loop.set_postfix(loss=loss.item())
    
train_loss = running_loss/len(loader)
train_losses.append(train_loss)

epochs.append(epoch)
scheduler.step()
```

And the training part

```
for epoch in range(1,NUM_EPOCHS):
    train_fn(train_loader, model, optimizer, loss_fn, scaler, epoch, scheduler)

    #save model
    checkpoint = {
        "state_dict": model.state_dict(),
        "optimizer":optimizer.state_dict(),
    }
    save_checkpoint(checkpoint)

    # check accuracy
    val_loss = check_accuracy(epoch, val_loader, model, loss_fn, device=DEVICE)
    val_losses.append(val_loss)
    # print some examples to a folder
    save_predictions_as_imgs(
        val_loader, model, folder="saved_images/", device=DEVICE
    )

    plt.plot(epochs, train_losses)
    plt.plot(epochs, val_losses)
    plt.xlabel('Epochs')
    plt.ylabel('Loss')
    plt.title('Loss function')
    plt.show()
```

And the check_accuracy

```
def check_accuracy(epoch ,loader, model, loss_fn, device="cuda"):
try:
    val_losses
except NameError:
    val_losses = []
num_correct = 0
num_pixels = 0
dice_score = 0
running_loss = 0
idx = 1
model.eval()

with torch.no_grad():
    for x, y in loader:
        # if idx <= 10:
        #     grid_data = make_grid(x)
        #     grid_mask = make_grid(y)
        #     f, axarr_val = plt.subplots(2,1)
        #     plt.title('Validation transform')
        #     axarr_val[0].imshow(grid_data.permute(1,2,0).numpy())
        #     axarr_val[1].imshow(grid_mask.permute(1,2,0).numpy())
        #     plt.savefig("transformacije/validation/fig" + str(epoch+1) + str(idx) + ".png")
        #     plt.close(f)
        #     idx = idx+1
        x = x.to(device)
        y = y.to(device).unsqueeze(1)
        preds = torch.sigmoid(model(x))
        preds = (preds > 0.5).float()
        num_correct += (preds == y).sum()
        num_pixels += torch.numel(preds)
        dice_score += (2 * (preds * y).sum()) / (
            (preds + y).sum() + 1e-8
        )
        loss = loss_fn(preds, y)
        running_loss += loss.item()
    val_loss = running_loss/len(loader)
print(
    f"Got {num_correct}/{num_pixels} with acc {num_correct/num_pixels*100:.2f}"
)
print(f"Dice score: {dice_score/len(loader)}")
print(f"Validation Loss: {val_loss}")
model.train()
return val_loss
```

I would be grateful if you could help anyway possible. Thank you.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRh89.png

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your model is overfitting to the data, especially given the size of your dataset compared to the size of your data. There is most likely nothing wrong with your code, but instead you should be using either a smaller model or increase the size of your dataset, or more likely both.

Edit: In the paper, the authors use a lot of data augmentation to make their model more robust by boosting the variance of inputs (effectively creating a larger dataset from the original 30 annotated images). As far as I can see, you currently are not using any augmentations in your training loop.

Comment: I am using albumentations for data augmentation(random crop and rotation). It's defined in the main function but i already checked if it augments the data differently for every epoch and it does so. Thank you for your response.